# PHP, MySql Stored Procedure with input parameters

Tags: php, mysql

I have the stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE `SignUp`(
IN p_emailid VARCHAR(100),
IN p_pwd VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
Insert into Users(
emailid,
pwd
)
values(
p_emailid,
p_pwd
);
END
```

In the PHP page:

```
include("config.php");

try{
$stmt = $DBH->prepare('CALL SignUp(:p_username, :p_password)');

$stmt->bindParam(':p_username','Hiiiiiiiiii',PDO::PARAM_STR,100);

$stmt->bindParam(':p_password','1111111111111',PDO::PARAM_STR,100);

$stmt->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
die();
}
```

I get the exception: Fatal error: Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Where it went wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's exactly what it says. You cannot pass a reference to a value, only to a variable. You need so rewrite the code like:

```
$username = 'Hiiiiiiiiii';
$password = '1111111111111';

$stmt->bindParam(':p_username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
$stmt->bindParam(':p_password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR,100);
```

Good luck!